# Drupal Gcal gcal_create_event()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, google-calendar-api

I am working with the GCal API with drupal 7 but I am stuck trying to create an event. I'm getting a call to undefined function error; however I think it might be something wrong with my arguments. Here is the code:

```
    $event =array( 
              'Summary'=> 'random',
              'Start'=> '2013-12-12 12:00:00',
              'End'=> '2013-12-12 13:00:00',
              'TimeZone'=> 'America/Los_Angeles',
              );
    $calendar_id='CALENDAR_ID';   //this was found off of the calendar settings page
    $account_name=gauth_account_load('test_account');
    $success=gcal_create_event($event, $calendar_id, $account_name);
```

I've already made sure that the calendar was public. The documentation is here: http://drupal.org/project/gcal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function name is slightly changed in drupal 7, It was gcal_create_event in drupal 6 but in drupal 7 I changed it to gcal_event_create.

You can just change last line of your code from

```
$success=gcal_create_event($event, $calendar_id, $account_name);
```

to

```
$success=gcal_event_create($event, $calendar_id, $account_name);
```

and should fix your problem.